# Not able to get updated data from web page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests 
URL = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/cigarettes/itc/ITC'
response = requests.get(URL)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
#     time.sleep(5)
var1 = float(soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'espopn'}).get_text().replace(",",""))
```

With this code, I am able to the value of var1, but the web page which I am accessing not showing real-time data once we land on the web page, it took 1 sec to update the real-time value once we land on the web page.

Due to which the value that I am getting in var1 is not a real-time value.
Wanted to know how I can wait once I land on the web page before doing web **scraping**.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So basically data is updaing dynamically and can you share that url if possible!

Comment: Without the URL it's impossible to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Here is the URL, https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/cigarettes/itc/ITC

Comment: @baduker Here is the URL, https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/cigarettes/itc/ITC

Comment: Do you want to find this ITC share price 215.95

Comment: @BhavyaParikh yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.As Data is updating dynamic so hard to get from `bs4` so you can try from api itself so how to find it

2.Go to chrome developer mode and then Network tab find xhr and now reload your website under Name tab you will find links but there are lot of

3.But on left side there is search so you can search price and from it gives url and you click on that go to headers copy that url and make call using `requests` module

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://api.moneycontrol.com/mcapi/v1/stock/get-stock-price?scIdList=ITC%2CVST%2CGPI%2CIWP540954%2CGTC&scId=ITC")
main_data=res.json()
main_data['data'][0]
```

Output:

```
{'companyName': 'ITC',
 'lastPrice': '215.25',
 'perChange': '-0.62',
 'marketCap': '264947.87',
 'scTtm': '19.99',
 'perform1yr': '7.33',
 'priceBook': '4.16'}
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: You can use this [url](https://api.moneycontrol.com/mcapi/v1/stock/get-stock-price?scIdList=ITC%2&scId=ITC) to make call and is shows only for ITC